# Is there a way to save ParseObject without make a HTTP request to the REST API?

Tags: mongodb, http, parse-server

I didn't find very much about this topic, so I wonder if it is an easy task to achieve or if it's actually not possible. My problem is that I have a lot of HTTP requests on my server even if a Cloud function is called only once. So I suppose that all the object updating / savings / queries are made by using the REST API. I have so many HTTP requests that several hundred are going timeout, I suppose for the huge traffic that it's generated.

Is there a way to save a ParseObject by executing the query directly to MongoDB? If it's not possible at the moment can you give me some hints if there are already some helper functions to convert a ParseQuery and a ParseObject to the relative in MongoDB so that I can use the MongoDB driver directly?

It's really important for my application to reduce HTTP requests traffic at the moment.

Any idea? Thanks!

EDIT:
Here an example to reproduce the concept:

Make a cloud function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', async (req, res) => {
  let testClassObject = new Parse.Object('TestClass');

  await testClassObject.save(null, {useMasterKey: true});

  let query = new Parse.Query('TestClass');

  let testClassRecords = await query.find({useMasterKey: true});

  return testClassRecords;
});
```

Make a POST request:
POST http://localhost:1337/parse/functions/hello

Capture HTTP traffic on port 1337 using Wireshark:
[image]

You can see that for 1 POST request other 2 are made because of the saving / query code. My goal would be to avoid these two HTTP calls and instead make a DB call directly so that less traffic will go through the whole webserver stack.

Link to the Github question: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/6549

Comment: No minimal reproducible example no help

Comment: @Smutje an example to demonstrate what? My question is more conceptual on the library workflow.

Comment: An example of where you need help. SO is not a place for discussions of theoretical nature but actual coding problems.

Comment: @Smutje I would need time to make a reproducible code...do you have suggestions on were to ask this theoretical question if not in SO?

Comment: @Smutje actually I've found a lot of questions without code on SO, even regarding how to use Desktop Software, the guideline writes that we can ask any question if it's related to any software development topic.

Comment: @Smutje okay added let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Parse Server `directAccess` option should do the magic for you. Please make sure you are initializing Parse Server like this:

```js
const api = new ParseServer({
  ...
  directAccess: true
});
...
```

Comment: Whats the downsides of this? If This option will be reduce server stress then why its not enabled by default? By enabling this will effect my server logic?

Comment: I follow the question from @UzaySan

Comment: @Simoyw I think if we enable directAccess. Parse server will redirect user request to MongoDB server. Which means Mongo server will be available to all IP adresses. This can be dangerous and any IP adress can reach our MongoDb server. But if we keep directAccess disabled we can close our mongoDb server to other IP adresses. And only our parse server can reach our mongo server. Also I assume if we enable directAcccess some features of parse will stop working like Class Level Permissions Or ACLs. These are the first things that come to my mind

Comment: This thing are just my guesses. Hope Davi will inform us.

Comment: @UzaySan I don't think so...mongodb is behing a firewall with ip restriction. I don't think this is the problem. I probably think that there is compatibility issues as it's a experimental feature.

Comment: @Simoyw Exactly. MongoDB should be behind a firewall and only some specific IP adresses can reach it. If we enable directAccess Parse will redirect requests and User IPs must be allowed to reach MongoDb in order to get data. If you enable directAccess but don't remove firewall user(Phone IP or Computer IP) cannot access data.

Comment: It does not make the MongoDB more vulnerable. When enabling this setting, instead of doing an api call to itself (that's the default behavior of the cloud code function), it goes directly to Mongo (from cloud code not client). It should have no downsides but it was an experimental feature released a while ago and it is not default because it could have some bugs. So I recommend you to test your app before going to production. Anyways, this feature is out for a while and we can think about turning it enabled by default.

Comment: tested and it works without any code changement at the moment. I've reduced server / proxy load to 69% by enabling this feature. Thanks for suggesting this feature!

Comment: Nice. I'm glad to know.